# Where can I download the REAL MonoDevelop Windows binaries?

Tags: mono, monodevelop, xamarin, xamarin-studio

The monodevelop.com website just takes me to this "Xamarin Studio" thing that has severe restrictions on the usage of the free version, and pricing that's almost as bad as Visual Studio on the paid versions! Is MonoDevelop for Windows dead? All I want to do is develop a GTK# application without installing Linux!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's used to be a version up on Sourceforge, but 9 years after I wrote this answer it seems to have disappeared. Sounds reasonable enough...

If you really need version 4 you'll have to [build it yourself](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Building_MonoDevelop). If you still have/find the sources that is.

Comment: Thanks! Actually found that .msi, but now I can't get it to install - it keeps demanding GTK# 2.12.9 or newer, and somehow the newer versions I have installed that came with Mono don't seem to satisfy it!

Comment: Installing the proper version of GTK# solved it! Wonder why it didn't like 2.12.20 or whatever I had before?

Comment: Why don't they provide Windows binaries anymore?

Comment: First link dead `Whoops, we can't find that page.`

Answer (score 13):

You do not have to pay to use Xamarin Studio to develop GTK# applications. There are no limitations whatsoever (except your imagination!) on what you can create with Xamarin Studio for the desktop.

You only have to pay if you want to develop applications for Android (and even for Android apps there is a free Starter edition).

Comment: But is there a size limitation on GTK# applications as there is with Android apps? I don't want to come up against a paywall halfway through the development process...

Comment: This is difficult information to find. I'd expect it on the [pricing](http://xamarin.com/faq#pricing) portion of the FAQ - or [MonoDevelop's FAQ](http://monodevelop.com/FAQ). It's not like the confusion [is new](http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?77965-MonoDevelop-vs-Xamarin-Studio-IDEs). And [here's a Team Xamarin guy last year saying they're different](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/5017/). I'm not saying Xamarin's doing a bad job being fair to the OSS community, but the good job could be communicated *much* more effectively.  ;^)

Comment: Is it possible to run & debug in Mono using Xamarin Studio (with the intent of targeting Mono on Linux)?

Comment: I researched it not long time ago. Restrictions in Xamarin Studio are not allowing to link some essential libraries without exceeding limits. Unusable. Seems Mono is dead unless you build it yourselves which is not easy as most of people say. It would be available as an installer otherwise.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of where he can download MonoDevelop.

Answer (score 8):

Honestly, it is a real pain in the butt to build MonoDevelop from the source or even to install on some platforms.

I did a lot of research and worked out for hours but still could not manage to build MonoDevelop and at the end of the day Decided to use SharpDevelop 4.3 (http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) instead and I gotta tell everybody that SharpDevelop is **easy peasy** to install. There are other alternatives too like Webbo, QuickSharp and Xamarin Studio but I haven't tried all of them.

If it is that easy to build MonoDevelop they would have build by them self and put an exe or a msi file or even a zip file with all the binaries and dependencies to download.

They have a similar problem which is quite annoying when it comes to installing the latest version of MonoDevelop on Ububtu or PC BSD.

First thing, I reckon its Git's problem but every time I downloaded the MonoDevelop source from its Git repo, the zip file is smaller than the real size and always corrupted.

Anyway I tried a few times and managed to download the source.
Then I downloaded and installed all the prerequisites.

I could not even open the Solution file in Microsoft Visual C# 2010 x86 (express).

Then I decided to build using MonoDevelop 3.0.6 as it is suggested in http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Building_MonoDevelop

When I tried to install MonoDevelop 3.0.6 it keeps on saying that I need to install GTK# 2.12.9 or newer even if I have already installed GTK# 2.12.22 (the latest one).

At the end I was really frustrated and decided to use SharpDevelop 4.3 as an alternative to M$ Visual Studio and MoNo-Develop.