# Install MonoDevelop / Xamarin studio 4.0.8 Gtk# version 2.12.16

Tags: android, installation, monodevelop, xamarin

Hey I am trying to instal monodevelop / Xamarin studio 4.0.8

I have installed: gtk-sharp-2.12.20.msi and .NET 4,

I get this error when installing: Gtk# version 2.12.16 or greater must be installed.

Is there a workaround?

I used download links from: http://monodevelop.com/Download

yes i have seen: [Where can I download the REAL MonoDevelop Windows binaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889462/where-can-i-download-the-real-monodevelop-windows-binaries)   but i hope that a new seloution is working now, when this is a newer version i am trying to install.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must install `gtk-sharp-2.12.22` first.

You can download it from [here](http://download.xamarin.com/GTKforWindows/Windows/gtk-sharp-2.12.22.msi).

Comment: Actually, yes. I had to setup that install separatly (even from Gtk# + Mono one). Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2):

Try passive install from the command prompt (cmd).

msiexec /i XamarinStudio-4.0.8.msi /passive

Comment: It did not do the trick :/ but i just installed visual studio instead, thanks for the try.